# how to mark and reuse reports and avoid deleting these marks

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

i have several reports in jasper, and i want to mark these reports by type so i can search these mark to find and reuse my reports

to do this i open the jrxml and add a comment in the header of the xml, with the mark @REPORTE and type name, for example:

@REPORTE informe con detalle de cobranza

the problem occurs when i compile the project, netbeans remove all my marks.
is there anyway to configure the netbeans avoid delete these marks

i using netbeans 7.2 the the ireport plugin

thanks